# Loop/Iterate in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'd like to include and enable some custom plug-ins in an official docker base image of an application.

Here is how directory structure looks like;

```
.
+-- Dockerfile
+-- plugins
|   +-- plugin_1
|   +-- plugin_2
|   +-- plugin_3
|   +-- ...
|   +-- plugin_n
```

Dockerfile looks like the following if I need to include plug-ins *plugin_1*, *plugin_3*, *plugin_7* and *plugin_8*;

```
FROM myapp_officialimage

COPY plugins/plugin_1/* /usr/lib/myapp/plugins/
RUN myapp-plugins.sh enable plugin_1

COPY plugins/plugin_3/* /usr/lib/myapp/plugins/
RUN myapp-plugins.sh enable plugin_3

COPY plugins/plugin_7/* /usr/lib/myapp/plugins/
RUN myapp-plugins.sh enable plugin_7

COPY plugins/plugin_8/* /usr/lib/myapp/plugins/
RUN myapp-plugins.sh enable plugin_8

CMD ["myapp-start.sh"]
```

**Question is**, is it possible to iterate/loop over a list in order to eliminate boilerplate above?

For example, Dockerfile like below would be cleaner and more maintainable;

```
FROM myapp_officialimage

ENV CUSTOM_PLUGIN_LIST="plugin_1 plugin_3 plugin_7 plugin_8"

for plugin in $CUSTOM_PLUGIN_LIST; \
do \
    COPY plugins/$plugin/* /usr/lib/myapp/plugins/ \
    RUN myapp-plugins.sh enable $plugin \
done

CMD ["myapp-start.sh"]
```

Comment: That will create two layers for in the image for every plugin. Can't you do this with a shell script? That will be one `RUN`.

Comment: Are these plugins possible to download as packages in some form? Then you'd make a requirements list and download the packages into the image.

Comment: `docker build` takes place in a build server whereas the built image will be executed in a production environment. The host in production doesn't include the `plugins` directory and production network doesn't have access for downloading plug-in files. I need to bundle these plug-ins before hand during compile&build time and then ship the resulting image to production.

Comment: Then I would just copy in a plugin folder and `RUN` a shell script that installs them. Whatever is in the `Dockerfile` only runs in your build system, so I don't understand why you are talking about production here.

Comment: I'd like to avoid copying unnecessary plug-ins into the container, I'd like to filter the necessary ones in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 4):

In your case I would prepare a new plugins folder together with a (possibly generated or handcrafted) script that installs them. Add the real plugins folder to `.dockerignore`. Then you copy in the new folder and run the install script. This also reduces the size of the context you upload to docker before the build starts. You are hand picking the dependencies anyway, so doing the work beforehand (before you `build`) should work fine.

In the build system you you should do something like:

```
collect_plugins.sh # Creates the new plugin folder and install script
docker build <params>
```

The two layers could then be:

```
COPY plugins_selected/ /usr/lib/myapp/plugins/
RUN  /usr/lib/myapp/plugins/install.sh
```

If you prepare the context you are sending to docker it will make the `Dockerfile` a lot more simple (a good thing). We are simply solving the problem before `build`.

Normally dependencies are fetched over the network using a package manager or simply by downloading them over http(s). Copying them into the build context like you are doing is not necessarily wrong, but it gets a bit more awkward.

**Let's look at how docker processes the `Dockerfile`** (slightly simiplified).

When you `build`, docker will upload all the files in the context to docker engine (except the paths mentioned in `.dockerignore`) and start processing the `Dockerfile`. The purpose is to produce filesystem layers that will represent the final image.

When you do operations like `RUN`, docker actually starts a container to execute the command(s) then adds the resulting layer to the image. The only thing that will actually run in production is what you specify in `CMD` and or `ENTRYPOINT` at the end of the `Dockerfile`.

Try to create as few layers as possible.

The [dockerfile best practices guide covers the basics](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).